# How much caulking do we need for a standard bathtub

Tags: caulk

How much caulking do we need to buy to caulk the rim of a standard 30" x 60" bathtub?

Comment: If you need more than one then your tile guy sucked.

Answer (score 2):

One standard caulk tube will do a tub plus another.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-10-1-oz-Clear-Silicone-2-Kitchen-and-Bath-Sealant-GE5040-12C/100663319

plus

https://www.homedepot.com/p/HDX-smooth-rod-caulk-gun-10-oz-HD109/203788465

The caulk link above - my go to.   The gun is just an example (that brand gun is actually crap and pushes out too much even when no pressure).

The way I caulk a tub is to run a first pass that goes as deep in as possible, hit it with a wet paper towel or sponge (push the caulk in), wait about a half hour, and then do the second coat and smooth the finish.

Comment: A squeeze type of tube or one that goes in a gun?

Comment: Squeeze?  Gun of course.

Comment: The tubes they have that you squeeze like tooth paste but larger, have not bought one of those but I see people pick them up all the time.

Comment: @EdBeal - Those are fine for touch up but for a new line I just can't see it.   They don't have any uniformity of the pressure and the caulk would be everywhere.   Also don't think one of the toothpaste tubes would do a tub.

Comment: The tubes are notorious for air pockets

Comment: Coats of silicone? It's commonly held that even silicone doesn't stick to silicone. I'm a one-pass guy. If it takes more than that the joint was too large to begin with and doesn't meet my standards.

Comment: Half an hour is past its working time, but no where near its curing. I'd like to see some of the work from someone who says the 'good' caulking guns are crappy and puts in twice as much work as the rest of us.

Comment: @Mazura - I have caulked probably close to 500 tubs - this I have down.   Silicone does not bind well with dried silicone.   Exactly why I said wait a half hour because silicone will bind with uncured silicone.   Also not sure how you do this in one pass because you will get very little in the crack where you need it without pressing.   Sure it will look good for 2-3 months but it will pull right off since it isn't anchored.   The comment I made on the gun was the specific gun I had a link for since I have bought and tried it and it has a pressure release issue.

Comment: How I do it? (grout, unless it's a plastic tub) I press it, make a mess, and use half a roll of paper towels... Why do you wait a half an hour, and not just do two beads one after another?

Comment: @Mazura - if you wait it hardens a little and there is less movement under.   Also if you wait you can clean up better from the first pass.   I also try to grout the tub/tile line unless it is the supercheap plastic thin ones.   Even if the grout cracks you can easily apply more.   Applying a little grout every 2-3 years is a 10 min job, a recaulk is probably a couple hours.    I don't think doing both passes on the caulk is bad - I just find it easier to wait.